# Use rooms in socket.io or iterate over connected users?

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, chat

I am developing a chat application to allow for one-on-one and group conversations. Everything is going well, except I am now stuck on a situation where I need some advice. The following is my setup:

I use node.js as backend server, develop in Swift for iOS, and use MongoDB to store everything. I use socket.io to provide real-time communication.

Now, I am wondering what the best approach is for the following situation. I want, when a message is received, for the other users to get notified in real-time if they are in the app (using a toast on top, or, if they are in the conversation, by appending the message to the chat history), but when they are not using the app, I want to send a push notification. Think Messenger, WhatsApp, ...

In my opinion, I have two choices, and I can't decide which one would be best, easiest to control, and most performant:

**Solution 1**

In this scenario I would, upon receiving a new message (through a node.js endpoint), find the relevant conversation from MongoDB, based on the conversation_id. From there, I'd retrieve a list of all the userIDs who are in this conversation (2 userIDs means one-on-one chat, more means group chat). Then, I could check for each userID if they are currently connected, because I store the active connections upon connecting, and remove them upon disconnecting. If they are connected, I'd emit the message to them, if they are not connected, I'd send a push notification.

The advantage of doing this, would be that I can send the message or a push notification fairly easily. The disadvantage would be that I need to iterate over all the users in a conversation for each message, e.g. if I emit 100 messages in 5 minutes to a group of 50 people, I'd have to find the users 100 times based on the conversation_id, and separately emit/send push notification of those 100 messages to the 50 people.

**Solution 2**

In this scenario I would use rooms, which in my opinion is specifically designed for this. I'd create a room for each conversation, and name it the same as in my MongoDB database, based on the conversation_id (e.g. 5e839693e0347bf2815be559). Then, when receiving a message, I'd simply emit the message to the relevant room, which would mean I only have to emit once. To do this, upon connecting, I would have to subscribe (join) all the rooms/conversations I am part of. That could mean I'd have to join 100, 200 or even more rooms every time I open the application, and leave them every time I close the app. It would also mean that I'd have to retrieve the members that are part of the conversation at the end after all, because I'd need to send the ones that are not connected a push notification.

So, my questions:

- What would be best? Solution 1, or solution 2?
- Is it a problem to iterate over the conversation members for every received message? Would this mean a lot of (unnecessary) overhead?
- How could I best handle the difference between emitting (to connected users) and sending a push notification (to unconnected users)?
- Is there a problem to join a lot of rooms every time I connect to the socket, and leave them every time I disconnect?

Any help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Iterating users in a room is trivial and fast.  They are just properties on an object in memory.  Joining or leaving rooms is just adding or removing a property from an in-memory object, also very fast.  The rest of your question are much, much more complicated and are a combination of opinion and design tradeoffs with many other considerations.  For example, rooms are an in-memory data structure that disappears if the server goes down and restarts vs your database which is persistent.  For example, will you ever need to cluster this server and have more than one server process?

Comment: Yes, there will at some point be multiple clusters.

Comment: If the server is clustered, you will be using some sort of database just for rooms (like the redis adapter so socket.io can work with clusters).  So, then it becomes a question of which database performs better for what you're doing with it.  It's no longer in-memory vs. database - it becomes database1 vs. database2.

Comment: Since yo're already storing everything in your current database and the data always has to be there anyway for persistence and offline user support, the question becomes more about will your database perform at the scale you need it to?  If not, then the question is more about how to fix that where using socket.io/redis/rooms is just one option for enhancing performance/scale.  Ultimately, this is not a theoretical question, but a question of deciding which scale measuring tests to run first, gather some data and then decide on next steps.

Comment: So, I do need to use rooms to be able to use clusters later on?

Comment: You don't "need" to use rooms.  They are a programming convenience for keeping track of groups of connected users that solve a particular problem.  You can solve that problem with rooms or with your database or with a combination of the two.  The question is no different if you are or aren't clustering.